# ZF2 validate min and max for number element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to limit users to be able to insert a maximum 9 numbers and also minimum  9 numbers inside `number` element. I try to use `Between` and `LessThan` but that not work? How can i validate this ?

Comment: Can you show your InputFilter config?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a `StringLength` validator for ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.string-length.html)

```
$value = '123456789';
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\StringLength(array('max' => 9, 'min' => 9));
$validator->isValid($value); // returns true
```

To check for numeric values only you can use [the `Digits` validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.digits.html#zend-validator-digits):

```
$value = '123456789';
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\Digits();
$validator->isValid($value); // returns true
```

So your 'number' input inside your input filter config could look like this:

```
'number' => array(
    'name' => 'number',
    'required' => true, //or false
    'filters' => array(
    ),
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array(
                'min' => 9,
                'max' => 9
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Digits',
        )
    )
),
```